# How to iterate through webelements to extract text from HTML tags in Selenium Web Automation (Python)?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am making a reddit bot that will look for certain attributes in comments, use selenium to visit the information website, and use `driver.find_elements_by...` to get the value inside those tags.

Now, `driver.find_elements_by...` is not iterable, and there are multiple `<span class="name">Lorem Ipsum</span>` tags with text inside them that I want obtained. I am storing this as a variable and replying to the comment via PRAW.

Suppose that the HTML is this:

```
<span class="name">Lorem</span>
<span class="name">Ipsum</span>
<span class="name">Dolor</span>
<span class="name">Sit</span>
<span class="name">Amet</span>
```

So, how could I obtain the text from all of the `<span class="name">` tags, and when I store it as a variable and reply, will it just put all the text together without spaces or will it format it with a space between each text, supposing that I write:

```
tags = driver.find_element_by...
comment.reply("Tags: {}".format(tags))
```

And if it just puts all the text together, how can I format it so that there are spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract the texts e.g. *Lorem*, *Ipsum*, *Dolor*, *Sit*, *Amet*, etc from all of the `<span>` using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) and [python](/questions/tagged/python) you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.name")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='name']")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['Lorem', 'Ipsum', 'Dolor', 'Sit', 'Amet']
  ```

> Note: This is list of type string and you can manipulate according to your requirement.

- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Outro

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)